# Which FTP client do you prefer and why?

Tags: ftp

I have question about FTP clients. Could anybody assist me with it? Which FTP client do you prefer and why?

Comment: I can not add new tags, but anybody who have rights, please add, ftp-client tag into my question.

Comment: Can you define "best" a little more? What are you looking for: fast, powerful, small, a GUI, some specific feature?

Comment: Done.  You should be able to edit your question.

Comment: Because there is no right or wrong answer to this question, but rather you are asking for an opinion, this question should probably be made Community Wiki.

Comment: now community wiki

Comment: And since it has very little to do with Server Management, and FTP is an antiquated protocol that should not be used for anything but anonymous file repositories, it should be modified to encompass something relevant to servers - like which FTP daemon is most secure.

Comment: well most of the people emphasis on FileZilla.

Comment: on the console ncftp with integrate bookmark feature is the best.
For automation lftp ist really cool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contrary to other opinions I'm not happy with Filezilla.

I prefer [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) on Windows (not pretty but full-featured) and [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) on OS X.

WinSCP is nice because of it's decent SFTP and SCP integration, and synchronised browsing. Also, it integrates with Pageant so I can login to all my server via my ssh keys.

Cyberduck is also full featured, but with quite an OS X interface. Nice is the support for Amazon S3 and CloudFiles cloudstorage services.

Comment: your answer is make sense to me. But I have no rights to vote you.

Comment: Now I'll have to go try this out, thanks for the detail.

Comment: @Kara Marfia: I like WinSCP features.

Comment: I use WinSCP as well- it's got a better UI by default, and is self-contained, as well.

Comment: @SilentW: It is also secure client.

Answer (score 19):

I use filezilla

Comment: I prefer this because it's feature-rich, it's free, it's updated frequently, and the interface isn't bad.  If there are additional ftp client features to be desired, I've never needed em.

Comment: Possibly most importantly, my users can figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Total Commander - The one and only.

If you're looking for SFTP / SCP support, go for WinSCP.

Answer (score 4):

For command line ftp clients, there's a few options:

- ftp - The original FTP client.  It works, but it's not the most friendly
  or featureful.
- lftp - Included by default on Red Hat based systems, it adds lots of
  useful features like tab completion for filenames/directories,
  and *lots* of other stuff.
- ncftp - Popular command line ftp
  client that also offers a 'visual'
  mode using the curses library.
- wget/curl - Not technically ftp clients, but they can handle ftp
  downloads.  Handy for scripting and one-off pulls where you know
  the URL (although lftp and ncftp can also handle one-off ftp pulls).

For GUI clients there's dozens of options, but most people will just use their web browser, which has an ftp client built in, for convenience.

Comment: +1 for lftp, and i wished i could vote twice for curl.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firefox, take a look at the [FireFTP](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) plugin.  I love it.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the "best" ftp program would read your mind and get the file for you.

I like to use scp (in *nix or Cygwin) because it works like a copy command; there's no session where you have to log in, then change directory, then ask for the file, etc.  Being secure is a bonus, if that matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer WinSCP over Filezilla on Windows.  I use Cyberduck on OSX and gFTP on Linux for GUI-based FTP clients.

Answer (score 2):

- [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) for OS X
- [gFTP](http://gftp.seul.org/) in Linux
- [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I have always used [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/), here is [one comparison with some other clients](http://linuxreviews.org/software/ftp-clients/).

Answer (score 1):

ftp - file transfer program

```
man 1 ftp
```

Answer (score 1):

Which platform?

On MacOS, I like Transmit (it's not free though), on Linux (and MacOS) I often use ncftp (CLI), otherwise Filezilla on every platform.

Comment: I will use ftp client on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of Core FTP. http://www.coreftp.com/

Note, this is non-commerical only for the free version, they do offer a paid version for around 24.95

I also believe it is Windows Only.

Answer (score 1):

- **Windows**: [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)
- **MacOS X**: [Cyberduck FTP](http://cyberduck.ch/)
- **Linux**: What ever is built in. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla is a good one, wget may be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

**[tnftp](http://freshmeat.net/projects/tnftp/)** - small, yet comfortable.  (Similar to NcFTP but without the annoying bits.)

Answer (score 1):

Like others here, Cyberduck on MacOS and FileZilla on Windows.  I haven't found a better free one for Windows, and Cyberduck is really fully-featured and talks to a bunch of stuff.  For example you can synchronize against WebDAV repositories including Sharepoint which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I know most will frown on this as its better to have a dedicated client really

If I am being lazy and using a web browser (firefox) then i normally use [fireftp](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) which can just be used as a firefox tool

or

web based version like [net2ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/) if im on someone elses computer who dont normally do any ftp transfers

WinSCP is great when you need to secure access

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla has the nicest support for multiple connections / protocols, though I wish the interface was a bit more customizable. I'd rather no local view, just a remote view within filezilla and drag/drop from my own explorer windows. As it stands right now, the only way I've found to hide the local view is to drag the separator to the far left, which isn't quite adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Konqueror is pretty good, if you're using KDE. It integrates with KWallet to save passwords. Using Konqueror with Kate you can seamlessly edit files on a remote server.

For console there is ncftp or mc.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use two for the majority of things I do:

1. Filezilla as a general purpose FTP client (though there are some interesting alternatives with high very high levels of windows integraton).
2. FTPSync [link text](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx) - this is absolutely brilliant for keeping local and remote folders in Sync.

Murph

Answer (score 1):

If you want a CLI, then lftp is hands down the winner in my opinion.  It includes support for  ftp,  ftps, http,  https,  hftp, fish, sftp and file.  More importantly it has good built-in scripting capabilities.  You can easily automate sftp transfers using password authentication -  something which is normally difficult to do without resorting to expert or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, define best...  I don't use ftp that much, and when I do:

- I use Internet Explorer internally because it's already on my PC and I can drag and drop files easily.
- I use Firefox for most ftp downloading.
- I use the command line ftp on windows as much as I use either of the others because it works fine for a couple files here and there and I can use it to get firefox if I don't have it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen WebDrive here yet, so I will add it. I like it because it's easy to set up and use, and you can map persistent drives. Also, for sysadmins, you can create settings and push them out to all of your users which really saves time.

Answer (score -1):

I use ["Auto FTP Manager"](https://www.deskshare.com/ftp-client.aspx). Auto FTP Manager moves files between any combination of FTP servers, PC folders, Android mobile devices and remote PCs. All the features are free to use. The automated and scheduled transfers are a breeze to setup. This product provides speed and security with SFTP and FTPS. Definitely better than Filezilla in experience.